# Loading a Spark 2.x DataFrame from MongoDB GridFS

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, gridfs

I've been using the [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/) to load DataFrames from MongoDB collections.

I'd like to move more of my ETL process into Spark and want to get 1-2 GB files into Spark from a Java service that does the basic file ingestion and parsing. Since I've already got a MongoDB cluster, it'd be easy to drop JSON-line format data into GridFS, and I'd rather not set up a cluster filesystem or HDFS just for this.

The Mongo Spark connector knows nothing of GridFS. The [MongoDB Connector for Hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) does have a GridFSInputFormat, documented in a [JIRA comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-271?focusedCommentId=1278118&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1278118).

I see the old `SparkContext` class has a `newAPIHadoopFile()` method that takes an InputFormat to build an RDD, but I thought `SparkSession` was the new hotness.

Is it possible to have Spark load a `DataFrame` from a Hadoop InputFormat like the GridFSInputFormat? I want to read a JSON-lines file from GridFS, infer the schema, and end up with a `DataSet[Row]`. And is there anything glaringly insane with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

No big deal in the end. I added the Mongo Hadoop connector:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop" % "mongo-hadoop-core" % "2.0.2"
```

And used it to get an `RDD[(NullWritable, Text)]`, which converts easily to `RDD[String]` with a call to `map`, and then to `DataFrame` with `sparkSession.read.json`:

```
/** Loads a DataFrame from a MongoDB GridFS file in JSON-lines format */
def loadJsonLinesFromGridFSFile(gridFsId: String): DataFrame = {
  jsonLinesToDataFrame(loadRDDFromGridFSFile(gridFsId))
}

/** Uses the Mongo Hadoop plugin to load an RDD of lines from a GridFS file */
private def loadRDDFromGridFSFile(gridFsId: String): RDD[String] = {
  val conf = new Configuration()
  val uri = config.uri.getCredentials
  conf.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/somedb.fs")
  conf.set("mongo.input.format", classOf[GridFSInputFormat].getName)
  conf.set("mongo.input.query", s"{ _id: { $$oid: '$gridFsId' } }")
  sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    conf, classOf[GridFSInputFormat], classOf[NullWritable], classOf[BinaryComparable]).map(_._2.toString)
}

private def jsonLinesToDataFrame(rdd: RDD[String]): DataFrame = {
  sparkSession.read.json(rdd)
}
```